# SQL noob trying to make schema Drizzle ORM

Tags: orm, drizzle, libdrizzle

**My confusion comes from how to structure the database so that I don't save duplicate data and when I update I don't leave the data (like promoting agent to lead)**

I am designing my db structure for the first time in MySQL (drizzle ORM). I have watched a lot of tutorials but I just can't seem to get the mental model on how to do this or even what would be the best way to do this.

The diagram is roughly what I am trying to do
where when a user logs in he is assigned a role

```js
enum UserRole {
  SUPER = "super",
  ADMIN = "admin",
  HOD = "hod",
  MANAGER = "manager",
  LEAD = "lead",
  AGENT = "agent",
  USER = "user",
}
```

now those roles define what actions the user can perform.

this is what is database structure supposed to represent.

- agent has one lead
- lead has one manager
- lead is in charge of one brand
- manager has one hod
- manager is in charge of multiple brands

```js
export const users = mysqlTable("user", {
  id: varchar("id", { length: 255 }).notNull().primaryKey(),
  // other user props
  role: varchar("role", { length: 255 }).default(UserRole.USER).$type<UserRole>().notNull(),
});

export const brands = mysqlTable(
  "brand",
  {
    id: bigint("id", { mode: "number" }).primaryKey().autoincrement(),
    name: varchar("name", { length: 256 }),
    description: varchar("description", { length: 256 }),
  },
  (brand) => ({
    brandNameIndex: index("name_idx").on(brand.name),
    brandIdIdx: index("brandId_idx").on(brand.id),
  })
);

export const hod = mysqlTable(
  "hod",
  {
    userId: varchar("userId", { length: 255 }).primaryKey(),
    createdByUserId: varchar("createdByUserId", { length: 255 }).notNull(),
    updatedAt: timestamp("updatedAt").onUpdateNow(),
  },
  (hod) => ({
    hodIdIdx: index("hodId_idx").on(hod.userId),
    createdByUserIdIdx: index("createdByUserId_idx").on(hod.createdByUserId),
  })
);

export const hodRelations = relations(hod, ({ one }) => ({
  user: one(users, { fields: [hod.userId], references: [users.id] }),
  createdBy: one(users, { fields: [hod.createdByUserId], references: [users.id] }),
}));

export const managers = mysqlTable(
  "manager",
  {
    userId: varchar("userId", { length: 255 }).notNull().primaryKey(),
    brandId: bigint("brandId", { mode: "number" }).notNull(),
    createdByUserId: varchar("createdByUserId", { length: 255 }).notNull(),
    updatedAt: timestamp("updatedAt").onUpdateNow(),
  },
  (manager) => ({
    managerIdIdx: index("managerId_idx").on(manager.userId),
    brandIdIdx: index("brandId_idx").on(manager.brandId),
    createdByUserIdIdx: index("createdByUserId_idx").on(manager.createdByUserId),
  })
);

export const managerRelations = relations(managers, ({ one, many }) => ({
  user: one(users, { fields: [managers.userId], references: [users.id] }),
  createdBy: one(users, { fields: [managers.createdByUserId], references: [users.id] }),
  brands: many(brands),
}));

export const leads = mysqlTable(
  "lead",
  {
    userId: varchar("userId", { length: 255 }).primaryKey(),
    managerId: bigint("managerId", { mode: "number" }).notNull(),
    createdByUserId: varchar("createdByUserId", { length: 255 }).notNull(),
    updatedAt: timestamp("updatedAt").onUpdateNow(),
  },
  (lead) => ({
    managerIdIdx: index("managerId_idx").on(lead.managerId),
    leadIdIdx: index("leadId_idx").on(lead.userId),
    createdByUserIdIdx: index("createdByUserId_idx").on(lead.createdByUserId),
  })
);

export const leadRelations = relations(leads, ({ one, many }) => ({
  manager: one(managers, { fields: [leads.managerId], references: [managers.userId] }),
  user: one(users, { fields: [leads.userId], references: [users.id] }),
  agents: many(agents),
}));

export const agents = mysqlTable(
  "agent",
  {
    userId: varchar("userId", { length: 255 }).primaryKey(),
    leadId: bigint("leadId", { mode: "number" }).notNull(),
    createdByUserId: varchar("createdByUserId", { length: 255 }).notNull(),
    updatedAt: timestamp("updatedAt").onUpdateNow(),
  },
  (agent) => ({
    agentIdIdx: index("agentId_idx").on(agent.userId),
    leadIdIdx: index("leadId_idx").on(agent.leadId),
    createdByUserIdIdx: index("createdByUserId_idx").on(agent.createdByUserId),
  })
);

export const agentRelations = relations(agents, ({ one }) => ({
  lead: one(leads, { fields: [agents.leadId], references: [leads.userId] }),
  user: one(users, { fields: [agents.userId], references: [users.id] }),
}));

export const commissionTarget = mysqlTable(
  "commissionTarget",
  {
    id: bigint("id", { mode: "number" }).primaryKey().autoincrement(),
    userId: bigint("agentId", { mode: "number" }).notNull(),
    target: bigint("target", { mode: "number" }).notNull(),
    month: int("month").notNull(),
    createdAt: timestamp("created_at")
      .default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)
      .notNull(),
    updatedAt: timestamp("updatedAt").onUpdateNow(),
  },
  (commissionTarget) => ({
    agentIdIdx: index("targetUser_idx").on(commissionTarget.userId),
  })
);

export const commissionTargetRelations = relations(commissionTarget, ({ one }) => ({
  user: one(users, { fields: [commissionTarget.userId], references: [users.id] }),
}));

export const commission = mysqlTable(
  "commission",
  {
    id: bigint("id", { mode: "number" }).primaryKey().autoincrement(),
    userId: varchar("userId", { length: 255 }).notNull(),
    amount: bigint("amount", { mode: "number" }).notNull(),
    month: int("month").notNull(),
    createdAt: timestamp("created_at")
      .default(sql`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)
      .notNull(),
    updatedAt: timestamp("updatedAt").onUpdateNow(),
  },
  (commission) => ({
    commissionUserIdIdx: index("commission_idx").on(commission.userId),
  })
);

export const commissionRelations = relations(commission, ({ one }) => ({
  user: one(users, { fields: [commission.userId], references: [users.id] }),
}));
```

with this code, I run into this error

```
Error: There is not enough information to infer relation "__public__.managers.brands"
```

The error seems to be from the relation of managers to brands

Please ask any clarifying questions if you have or suggest improvements in the model

[image: DB diagram]